# fill in the form's values with what the user had typed

Tags: php, html

i am trying to validate the form on the same page, but i am getting an error. i want to fill in the form’s values with what the user had typed. the html code is:

```
<h4>Business Name</h4></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bname" size="30" required x-moz-errormessage="Enter business name" <?php if ( "$_POST[bname]" ) { echo " value='" . $_POST['bname'] . "'";} ?> ></td></tr>
```

and the error message is:  Undefined index: bname in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\registration.php
>

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the `$_POST['bname']`  `isset`, if yes, then `echo`

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['bname'])) { echo " value='" . $_POST['bname'] . "'";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST['bname']) ) { echo " value='" . $_POST['bname'] . "'";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your the condition in your if statement read as follows?

```
<td><input type="text" name="bname" size="30" required x-moz-errormessage="Enter business name" <?php if ( isset($_POST['bname']) ) { echo " value='" . $_POST['bname'] . "'";} ?> ></td></tr>
```